# use c# .net graphclient to move message to another folder

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am logged into the graph as an application.  My console application is processing emails of a shared mailbox.  When the processing is done, I want to move the message out of the inbox to another folder.
I get this error: Additional information: Code: ErrorInvalidIdMalformed
Message: Id is malformed.

But, I have just used the message.Id to download all the attachments.

```
IMessageAttachmentsCollectionPage attachments = await graphClient.Users[inbox].Messages[message.Id].Attachments.Request().GetAsync();
```

^-- this is working

A few lines later...

```
Message movedMsg = await graphClient.Users[inbox].Messages[message.Id].Move("01 Processed").Request().PostAsync();
```

^-- this gives the Id is malformed error above.

Does anyone have any advice?
Thanks in Advance. -Laurie

Comment: use intermediate variables and your debugger

Comment: yes, I have stepped through all the code... the message.Id is the same value as it was in the first call. Maybe the Id that is having a problem is "01 Processed".  The example I saw on github used the folder name, so I think that should be correct.

Comment: Is '01 processed' a valid mail folder id? [Here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/mailfolder_move) is more detail about the 'move' operation.

Comment: @DmitryPimenov I think you are right, "01 Processed" is not a valid mail folder id.  If I replace it with "Drafts"... the email is moved to the drafts folder.  How do I get the Folder Id of a folder that is not one of the "well known" folders?

Comment: You can query the name folders a user has (and each of their ids) by making a GET request to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<user id>/mailfolders?$expand=childfolders` first. The response body will include each of the nested child folders.

Comment: I ended up adding code to search all the folders, look for the display names I wanted, and saving the Id for those folders.

Comment: @DmitryPimenov Wish there was more documentation for using Microsoft.Graph.dll

Answer (score 3):

```
IUserMailFoldersCollectionPage allMailFolders = await graphClient.Users[inbox].MailFolders.Request().GetAsync();
        foreach(MailFolder folder in allMailFolders)
        {
            if (folder.DisplayName == "01 Processed")
            {
                processedFolder = folder.Id;
            }
            if (folder.DisplayName == "02 Needs Attention")
            {
                needsAttentionFolder = folder.Id;
            }
        }

 if (needsAttention)
                {
                    needsAttentionCount++;
                    Message movedMsg = await graphClient.Users[inbox].Messages[message.Id].Move(needsAttentionFolder).Request().PostAsync(); 
                }
               else
                {
                     Message movedMsg = await graphClient.Users[inbox].Messages[message.Id].Move(processedFolder).Request().PostAsync();
                }
```

Comment: Seems like there should be an easier way.

Comment: I don't see what's difficult about this.

The fluent api provides everything that you need.